# cakephp unique date validation

Tags: jquery, validation, date, cakephp

i m working on a project in cakephp. i have a datepicker in my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('date1', array('div' => false,'type'=>'text','label'=>false,'class'=>'smallInput','tabindex'=>'4','id'=>'date1','style'=>'width:100px')); ?>
```

and here's the jquery code:

```
$(function() { $("#date1").datepicker({ minDate: 0 ,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}); });
```

i want to make sure the user selects a date which is already not present in the database. can i achieve this through a function in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'isUnique'  :

```
   var $validate = array(
        'date1' => array(
        'unique' => array(
          'rule' => 'isUnique'

        )
    );
```

[Date validation cake book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)

Comment: the "on create" part is usually not necessary. on update Cake knows to exclude the current record for it.

Comment: and linking to the official documentation would also be helpful.

Comment: thanks...what if i have to ensure unique records for a particular ID?

Comment: i don't understand your question :s. Can you deepen your explanation ?

Comment: i am storing certain details along with the date, such as a user ID. so if user A selects a date, it can be available for user B, but user A cannot use it again.

Comment: maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461267/cakephp-isunique-for-2-fields/2464201#2464201) can help you.