# Cakephp 2.x: isUnique validation for two fields combined

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I have a model that consists of 3 fields, `ID`, `Language`, `Filename`. How can i prevent to save a new record if there is an existing record with same `Filename` and `Language`. For example

```
1. ID: 0001    Language: EN     Filename:Test.pdf
```

If I try to add another record with `Language` EN and `Filename` Test.pdf to show an error. I want to do it in the model. Bear in mind that i am new to `CakePHP`.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461267/cakephp-isunique-for-2-fields

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule to the $validate array in your model:

```
public $validate = array(
   'Filename' => array(
        'rule' => array('isUnique', array('Language', 'Filename'), false),
        'message' => 'The File already exists in the specified Language ',
        'required' => 'create'
    )
);
```

From the [CakePHP 2.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique).

Comment: This rule works correctly on adding but for some reason every time i am trying to edit an existing record it always fails on saving. If i remove the above rule then everything is fine.

Comment: I've updated the answer so that the rule is only enforced when adding new entries.